# On Brylinski–McLaughlin's paper "Čech cocycles for characteristic classes"

Tags: characteristic-classes, chern-classes, cech-cohomology

In the paper ["Čech cocycles for characteristic classes"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02104916), the authors Brylinski and McLaughlin describe how to construct Čech cocycles with values in the Deligne smooth complex representing the Euler, Pontryagin and Chern classes, respectively.

In the beginning of the paper, the authors assume that the manifold $M$ is compact but it is not obvious to me where they use the compactness assumption. I suspect that they need the compactness for the cocycle formulæ with integrals in Theorems 2, 3 and 4, but I am not certain. Does anyone know anything about that? Moreover, is someone aware if the construction presented in the Brylinski–McLaughlin's paper has been generalised to non-compact manifolds? Moreover, does their construction have an algebro-geometric version?